# Are transient response, natural response, impulse response same thing?

Tags: system

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_response), they are equivalent. Is this correct?

Comment: The wikipedia page does not even claim that all three are the same thing

Comment: Are they same thing or not?

Comment: See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93064

Comment: So, if  a system is given impulse as input, then natural response would be its output?

Comment: No. Your question just means you misunderstood the link discussion.

Comment: Transients respond more impulsively, naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural response is the zero input response (i.e. response to initial conditions).

Impulse response is (unsurprisingly) the response to a unit impulse - the Laplace Transform of a unit impulse response is the transfer function.

Transient response is a generic term that applies to any time-domain component of a response that decays to a steady state value.