# Solving capacitor voltage with Laplace

Tags: voltage, laplace-transform

I saw this example and I got confused.

[image]

The example shows: \$V_{C}(s)=\dfrac{R\parallel\frac{1}{sC}}{sL+R\parallel\frac{1}{sC}}V_{in}(s)\$ .

Isn't it enough to express \$V_{C}(s)\$ with the voltage drop in the resistor since it should have the same voltage too (\$V_{R}(s)=V_{C}(s)\$), or is there something with Laplace that makes it different?
Wouldn't it be the same in this case:

\$V_{C}(s)=\dfrac{R}{sL+R}\cdot V_{in}(s)\$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it enough to express VC(s) with the voltage drop in the resistor since it should have the same voltage too (VR(s)=VC(s)), or is there something with Laplace that makes it different?

It isn't enough and it's different. How much have you read about Laplace? It simplifies LTI system from differential equations and models three important factors: frequency, transient, and steady-state. Plugging in or out just a single component and also giving different inputs could lead into different responses.

---

I just found the exact model of your question with useful transient and frequency analysis that might help you further understanding this topic.

1. Go to this page: [RLC Low-Pass Filter Design Tool](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/RLClowkeisan.htm) from OKAWA Electric Design Website
2. Scroll down till you find
   **"Calculate the transfer function for RLC low-pass filter with R, L and C values"**

   [image: RLC Low-Pass Filter Design Tool from OKAWA Electric Design Website]
   *Figure 1. RLC Low-Pass Filter Design Tool from OKAWA Electric Design Website*
3. Adjust the value of the component, choose the analysis option that you wanted.
4. Click Calculate

---

For example, with my option above, I got the following result.

[image: RLC LPF Charateristics]
*Figure 2. RLC LPF Charateristics*

[image: RLC LPF Frequency Response]
*Figure 3. RLC LPF Frequency Response*

[image: RLC LPF Transient Response against step input]
*Figure 4. RLC LPF Transient Response with step input*

Please note that you need practical consideration if you want to actualize it, lets say breadboard or something.

Have fun!

---

## Edit

> Thank you for your response! But my question is more conceptual and it
>   goes more in the math expression rather than to see the actual
>   response of the system depending on its values. Specifically. Why does
>   the resistor influence the voltage on vC. Since voltage divisor is
>   used, then the voltage on the capacitor should be the capacitor's
>   impedance (in Laplace terms) divided by the sum of the resistances
>   times the voltage input as I responded to @Justme above

The resistor is connected in parallel with the capacitor, that's why it's influencing each other. As simple as that.

- The complete ideal RLC LPF ZIC transfer function (with R as the load only)

  \$
    \begin{aligned}
    \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} &= \dfrac{R\parallel\frac{1}{sC}} 
    {sL+R\parallel\frac{1}{sC}}\\
    &= \dfrac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\frac{1}{RC}s+\frac{1}{LC}}
    \end{aligned}
    \$

- Only ideal LC LPF ZIC transfer function ([LC Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit))

  \$
     \begin{aligned}
     \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} &= \dfrac{\frac{1}{sC}}{sL+\frac{1}{sC}}\\
     &= \dfrac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\frac{1}{LC}}
     \end{aligned}
     \$

- Only ideal RL LPF ZIC transfer function. ([Simulation](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/LRlowkeisan.htm))

  \$
     \begin{aligned}
     \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} &= \dfrac{R}{sL+R}\\
     &= \dfrac{\frac{R}{L}}{s+\frac{R}{L}}
     \end{aligned}
     \$

If only the inductor left out, it's straightforward that \$V_{out} = V_{in}\$.

The 2nd order type 0 LTI system ZIC with no zero can be represented as follows

$$
  \dfrac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \dfrac{DC_{gain} \  \omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta 
  \omega_n s + \omega_n^2 }\\
  $$

If you take out the resistor or choose it extremely high then what happens? Take a look at its transfer function. The [damping ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio) will be equal to zero. What does that mean? The system is undamped, and if you give an unit step input, its output will oscillate forever. The frequency of the oscillation determined by [natural frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_frequency) \$\omega_n\$, also known as eigenfrequency, which is the frequency at which a system tends to oscillate in the absence of any driving or damping force. 
FWIW, [DC gain useful Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138737/dc-gain-of-a-transfer-function).

What about the RL one? It's not second order system anymore.

The 1st order type 0 LTI system ZIC with no zero can be represented as follows

$$
  \dfrac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \dfrac{DC_{gain} \  \frac{1}{\tau}}{s + \frac{1}{\tau} }\\
  $$

The time constant of a first-order system is \$\tau\$ which is equal to the time it takes for the system's response to reach 63% of its steady-state value for a step input (from zero initial conditions) or to decrease to 37% of the initial output value for a system's [unforced response](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93061/difference-between-natural-response-and-forced-response).

For the time-domain ZIC point of view you can derive and observe it by inverse laplace transform the equations above (if you inverse the transfer function, you'll get impulse response of course, so rearrange it so that you can give it an input).

Comment: Thank you for your response!
But my question is more conceptual and it goes more in the math expression rather than to see the actual response of the system depending on its values. 
Specifically. Why does the resistor influence the voltage on \$v_{C}\$. Since voltage divisor is used, then the voltage on the capacitor should be the capacitor's impedance (in Laplace terms)  divided by the sum of the resistances times the voltage input as I responded to @Justme above.

Comment: @FelipeMedLev Please take a look at updated answer above.

Comment: @FelipeMedLev If there's anything missing or you're dissatisfied with something just say it okay. I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that voltage over R and C are equal. But current is not. And current depends on frequency. DC won't pass the capacitor so there is only resistor. But at very high frequencies the capacitor is a short so there won't be any voltage over R and C. Basically your equation just removed the capacitor completely, which might be a solution if circuit was examined only at DC frequency of zero.

Comment: Oh. In that case, wouldn't it be then equivalent to: \$v_{C}(s)=\dfrac{\frac{1}{sC}}{sL+\frac{1}{sC}}V_{in}(s)\$?